# A limit depending on $a$, $b$ and $\alpha$

Tags: analysis, limits

I was doing some analysis problems and stumbled upon this one which I have no idea what to do with:

> Evaluate
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+a)^\alpha-(n+b)^\alpha$$
>   depending on $a$, $b$ and $\alpha$.

It seems to me like it should diverge when $\alpha>0$ and $a\neq b$ and be $0$ otherwise, and the only thing I tried is looking at $(x+a)^\alpha-(x+b)^\alpha$ and showing it's unbounded by looking at the derivative, but couldn't prove anything. Could anyone give me a **hint** on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case where $\alpha \leq 0$ and the case when $a=b$ are both fairly easy: you get convergence to zero.

For $\alpha > 0$ and $a \neq b$, we can do the following factoring trick:

$$(n+a)^\alpha - (n+b)^\alpha = n^\alpha \left ((1+a/n)^\alpha - (1+b/n)^\alpha \right )$$

Now linear approximation tells us that

$$(1+a/n)^\alpha = 1 + \alpha a/n + o(1/n).$$

Hence

$$(n+a)^\alpha - (n+b)^\alpha = n^{\alpha - 1} \left ( \alpha a - \alpha b + o(1) \right ).$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you very much! So, it converges when $\alpha\le1$ or $a=b$, if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: @ryagami Yes. Note also that the limit is not zero if $\alpha = 1$ and $a \neq b$ (as you would expect, for in this case the sequence is always the value $a-b$).

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. Thanks again! :)